# Select all rows in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a function that aims at printing the `sum` along a column of a `pandas` `DataFrame` after filtering on some rows to be defined ; and the percentage this quantity makes up in the same sum without any filter:

```
def my_function(df, filter_to_apply, col):
    my_sum = np.sum(df[filter_to_apply][col])
    print(my_sum)
    print(my_sum/np.sum(df[col]))
```

Now I am wondering if there is any way to have a `filter_to_apply` that actually doesn't do any filter (i.e. keeps all rows), to keep using my function (that is actually a bit more complex and convenient) even when I don't want any filter.

So, some `filter_f1` that would do: `df[filter_f1] = df` and could be used with other filters: `filter_f1 & filter_f2`.

One possible answer is: `df.index.isin(df.index)` but I am wondering if there is anything easier to understand (e.g. I tried to use just `True` but it didn't work).

Comment: But ```pandas.apply(func)``` doesn't do any filtering. Isn't it enough for your use case? I guess you would need to swap ```print(...)``` with ```return ...``` to some extent there.

Comment: Yes, there is probably a workaround, I was just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Your suggested `df[df.index.isin(df.index)]` is actually the only code I found so far that works in my example, thanks. Using `df[slice(-1)` seems to select only all but the last row…? An alternative is `df[df.index != None]`, but Pycharm will display a warning.

Comment: If you know that indexes are positive, you can also use `df[df.index >= 0]`.

Answer (score 2):

A Python slice object, i.e. `slice(-1)`, acts as an object that selects all indexes in a indexable object. So `df[slice(-1)]` would select all rows in the `DataFrame`. You can store that in a variable an an initial value which you can further refine in your logic:

```
filter_to_apply = slice(-1)  # initialize to select all rows

... # logic that may set `filter_to_apply` to something more restrictive

my_function(df, filter_to_apply, col)
```

Comment: Thanks !! Also realized in the meantime that `pd.Series(data = [True]*len(df), index = df.index)` could work but much less elegant and can't be used as default argument of a function as it depends on `df`. So you definitely nailed it !

Comment: not sure if I'm missing something, but for me, df[slice(-1)] selects all BUT the last row? :O

Comment: @MatthiasLuh that's actually right - I had not paid enough attention.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to select all rows:

```
df[range(0, len(df))]
```

this is also

```
df[:]
```

But I haven't figured out a way to pass `:` as an argument.

Comment: You can use `slice(-1)` to act like `:` such as: `df[slice(-1)]` and even better: `index = slice(-1); df[index]`

Answer (score 0):

Theres a function called `loc` on pandas that filters rows. You could do something like this:

```
df2 = df.loc[<Filter here>]

#Filter can be something like df['price']>500 or df['name'] == 'Brian'
#basically something that for each row returns a boolean

total = df2['ColumnToSum'].sum()
```